# Text in excel cell is not showing,but it is showing in formula bar

Tags: excel

I am using **Microsoft excel 365** when suddenly the data inputed in some cells doesn't show up but shows up when I check the formula bar.I tried comparing it with other cells but couldn't find the cause. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Font color? Special formatting?

Comment: Save and close file. Restart excel and it then works correctly. At least in my experience with 36 computers in a computer lab with students. Think it is a memory thing.

Comment: Done but no changes appear.

Comment: Check to see if the Number Format is set to Custom (as P.b. mentioned). If so, try changing to General or some other format. It's possible to set up a Custom Format to hide the display of a cell value (when one wants to mess with people's minds).

Comment: No it was set as general from the beginning I tried changing it but it still showed the same.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.